# What's the most pythonic way of importing many packages from the current directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's suppose I have 20 packages that I need to import from the current directory that have __ init __.py inside of them.

```
from . import x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12, x13, x14, x15, x16, x17, x18, x19, x20
```

So each individual structure is:

```
x1/__init__.py
```

How can I import all of them from '.'? What's the most pythonic way of importing many many packages or all of them in this case?

Edit: `from . import *` does not work with packages.

Comment: I suspect the best way is to redesign your module structure so that a module doesn't depend on 20 others. This indicates either your "main" script is doing too much, or the individual modules are each doing too little.

Answer (score 2):

I created your package structure this way:

```sh
d=q64611308

for i in $(seq 20); do
  mkdir -p "${d}/x${i}"
  echo "print('imported x${i}')" > "${d}/x${i}/__init__.py"
done
```

The `q64611308/__init__.py` file is:

```py
from importlib import import_module
from pprint import pprint

# from . import x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12, x13, x14, x15, x16, x17, x18, x19, x20
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "./__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
#    from . import x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12, x13, x14, x15, x16, x17, x18, x19, x20
# ImportError: cannot import name 'x1'

modnames = [f"x{i}" for i in range(1, 21)]

for modname in modnames:
    print(f"importing {modname}")
    locals()[modname] = import_module(modname)

pprint(locals())
```

These:

```sh
$ python3 q64611308/__init__.py
$ cd q64611308; python3 ./__init__.py
```

will both print:

```sh
importing x1
imported x1
importing x2
imported x2
[...]
importing x19
imported x19
importing x20
imported x20
{'__annotations__': {},
 '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>,
 '__cached__': None,
 '__doc__': None,
 '__file__': './__init__.py',
 [...]
 'pprint': <function pprint at 0x1080817b8>,
 'x1': <module 'x1' from '[...]/stackoverflow/q64611308/x1/__init__.py'>,
 'x10': <module 'x10' from '[...]/stackoverflow/q64611308/x10/__init__.py'>,
 [...]
 'x8': <module 'x8' from '[...]/stackoverflow/q64611308/x8/__init__.py'>,
 'x9': <module 'x9' from '[...]/stackoverflow/q64611308/x9/__init__.py'>}
```

Comment: Well in real life the names of the packages are not 'x's, they all have different names without a pattern. It was just an example.

Comment: Yes, I supposed but no problem: just put your real module names in the `modnames` list :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use * to include everything.

```
from . import *
```

Answer (score 0):

I think to fix the x1, x2, x3 etc. problem you can just use

```
from . import *
```

Comment: Please avoid duplicate answers.

Comment: On my page I posted the comment before Daniel did :/

Comment: Using the "Oldest" tab I can see Daniel published his answer first. It's alright this time.